# Pygame with functions/creating a new page

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

Below is the code to a game I am trying to make in my python beginners class for highschool. The problem I keep running into is that I made a button function but every time I click the button it will show the level select function(the one I want) but only the time that I have my mouse clicked but as soon as I let go the it goes back to the main menu. If anyone could help me i would greatly appreciate it :)

```
Imports
import pygame
import time
import random

# Define some colors
BLACK    = (   0,   0,   0)
WHITE    = ( 255, 255, 255)
GREEN    = (   0, 255,   0)
RED      = ( 255,   0,   0)

pygame.init()

#Music and Sound Imports
pygame.mixer.music.load("MenuMusic.wav")

# Set the width and height of the screen [width, height]
size = (1920, 980)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

pygame.display.set_caption("Panda On The Run v1")

# Loop until the user clicks the close button.
done = False

# Used to manage how fast the screen updates
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

#Main Menu
Main_menu = pygame.image.load("Main Menu Backgroundv3.png")


    # -------- Main Program Loop -----------
def level_select():
    screen.fill(WHITE)

def button(msg, x,y,ic,ac,action = None):
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
    #Level Select Colour Change
    if x + 625 > mouse[0] > x and y + 225 > mouse[1] > y:
        font = pygame.font.SysFont('Calibri', 100, True, False)
        text = font.render(msg,True,ac)
        screen.blit(text, [90, 420])
        if click[0] == 1 and action != None:
            if action == "level":
                level_select()

    else:
        font = pygame.font.SysFont('Calibri', 100, True, False)
        text = font.render(msg,True,ic)
        screen.blit(text, [90, 420])

    #Settings Colour Change
    if 1300 + 1900 > mouse[0] > 1300 and 350 + 250 > mouse[1] > 350:
        font = pygame.font.SysFont('Calibri', 100, True, False)
        text = font.render("Settings",True,RED)
        screen.blit(text, [1450, 420])
    #Controls Colour Change
    if 35 + 800 > mouse[0] > 35 and 600 + 500 > mouse[1] > 600:
        font = pygame.font.SysFont('Calibri', 100, True, False)
        text = font.render("Controls",True,RED)
        screen.blit(text, [150, 770])
    #About Panda Run
    if 1285 + 625 > mouse[0] > 1285 and 677 + 250 > mouse[1] > 677:
        font = pygame.font.SysFont('Calibri', 80, True, False)
        text = font.render("About Panda Run",True,RED)
        screen.blit(text, [1325, 775])




#Main Intro
def game_intro():
    #pygame.mixer.music.play(5)
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
    intro = True
    while intro:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            print(event)
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
        screen.blit(Main_menu, [0,-100])

        #Level Select 
        font = pygame.font.SysFont('Calibri', 100, True, False)
        text = font.render("Level Select",True,BLACK)
        screen.blit(text, [90, 420])

        #Settings
        font = pygame.font.SysFont('Calibri', 100, True, False)
        text = font.render("Settings",True,BLACK)
        screen.blit(text, [1450, 420])

        #Controls
        font = pygame.font.SysFont('Calibri', 100, True, False)
        text = font.render("Controls",True,BLACK)
        screen.blit(text, [150, 770])

        #About Panda Run
        font = pygame.font.SysFont('Calibri', 80, True, False)
        text = font.render("About Panda Run",True,BLACK)
        screen.blit(text, [1325, 775])

        button("Level Select", 35,335,BLACK,RED,"level")

        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(15)




    # First, clear the screen to white. Don't put other drawing
    # above this, or they will be erased with this command.

    # --- Go ahead and update the screen with what we've drawn.
    pygame.display.flip()

    # --- Limit to 60 frames per second
    clock.tick(60)

# Close the window and quit.
# If you forget this line, the program will 'hang'
# on exit if running from IDLE.
game_intro()
pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include the desired behavior, *a specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: it returns to main menu because `level_select()` does nothing - It fills screen with white color and then it returns to `bottom()` and you are again in main menu. Don't expect that (almost) empty function will do some magic.

Answer (score 0):

It returns to main menu because `level_select()` does nothing. It fills screen with white color and then it returns to `bottom()` and you are again in main menu. Don't expect that (almost) empty function will do some magic.

If you what to stay in `level_select` then you have to do something.

If `level_select` has to display new menu or something then create in this function new "mainloop" which will display elements in `level_select`, check events, etc.

Every `"stage"` needs own `"mainloop"` (`"while running"` on image) like this:

[image]

But it can be easier if you work with classes.

"Stage example" on GitHub: [furas/python-examples/pygame/stage-example](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/blob/master/pygame/stage-example/main.py)